# Java RX, why this line is called twice and these 2 line never called

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am new to Java Rx, I don't know if that is a valid question or not.

I have function

```
    public Single<PayResponse> pay(PayRequest apiRequest) {

                return client.initiatePayment(apiRequest)
                        .doOnSuccess(initiatePaymentResponse -> {
                            System.out.println("first");
                            client.confirmPayment(initiatePaymentResponse.getPaymentId())
                                    .doOnSuccess(confirmPaymentResponse -> {System.out.println("second");doConfirmationLogic(confirmPaymentResponse ))}
                                    .doOnError(ex -> {System.out.println("thirs");ex.printStackTrace();logError(ex);});
                        })

                        .doOnError(ex -> {ex.printStackTrace();logError(ex);});
            }
```

after executing this method i can find **`first`** was printed twice but neither **`second`** nor **`third`** was printed

It is odd behaviour for me, because i expect to find **`first`** and **`second`** or **`third`**.

Any idea ?

Comment: Sources when not subscribed to do nothing. You have to use `flatMap` instead of `doOnSuccess`. You may be getting `first` twice because you subscribe to the result of `pay()` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to start receiving the emitted value(s) from an observable (like a `Single<T>`), you must `subscribe()` to it first.

You are probably only subscribing to the `Single` returned by `pay` twice somewhere else, and that's why you see `first` printed two times. In the code you show, I can see that are not subscribing to any of the observable there, so nothing will happen afterwards.

If you want to chain observables, the most common choice would be to use the `flatMap` operator (there are other options as well).

In your case, it would look similar to this:

```
public Single<PayResponse> pay(PayRequest apiRequest) {

    return client.initiatePayment(apiRequest)
                .flatMap(initiatePaymentResponse -> {
                        System.out.println("first");
                        return client.confirmPayment(initiatePaymentResponse.getPaymentId();
                })
                .flatMap(confirmPaymentResponse -> {
                        System.out.println("second");
                        return doConfirmationLogic(confirmPaymentResponse);
                })
               .doOnSuccess(confirmationLogicResponse -> System.out.println("third"))
               .doOnError(ex -> {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        logError(ex);
                });
}
```

Then, you subscribe to the single returned by `pay` somewhere else like this:

```
...
pay(apiRequest)
     .subscribe(onSuccesValue -> {
             // The whole chain was successful and this is the value returned 
             // by the last observable in the chain (doConfirmationLogic in your case)
      }, onError {
             // There was an error at some point during the chain
      }
...
```

I am supposing that all the methods `initiatePayment`, `confirmPayment`, `doConfirmationLogic` return `Singles` and that `doConfirmationLogic` ends up returning a `Single<PayResponse>`. If that's not the case, you will need to make some small changes, but you get the general idea of how chaining observables work.